# Request Paypal's IPN to send Authorization token in headers to my webhook

Tags: java, web-services, paypal, swagger, paypal-ipn

I've been struggling with Paypal's IPN for a couple of days now because I've done the IPN webhook thing before without problem, but this time messages weren't received by my Web service.

After some thinking I found that I was getting a 401 status code from paypal because my service API is under some security with Swagger which requires me to pass an HTTP header with this format:

`Authorization: Bearer foobar`

However I haven't found in Paypal's docs if this is possible, I mean to add an authorization token along with the transaction send my Paypal, so my API is able to accept the message.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478293/how-do-i-make-paypal-to-send-ipn-to-my-server-with-simple-http-authentication) suggests to make use of the IPN's `custom` variable, which might be OK if I wanted to send the DB user's ID or something like that, however I don't think it might be useful in this case due to the message being rejected by Swagger before being processed at all...

Not sure if useful for the question but:

- Our webservice is made with Java
- I have configured the URL in Paypal's sandbox and got a 401 status code
- The webservice is as simple as printing the transaction's ID sent by Paypal in console.
- The way I call Paypal's IPN is with Paypal generated buttons